# After upgrade to Intellij IDEA 2017.1 ESLint stopped working

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, eslint

I installed Intellij IDEA 2017.1 and imported my settings from old 2016.3.

After that I decided to analyze the code with ESLint, but unfortunately got the following error:

```
TypeError: cliEngine.getFormatter(...) is not a function
    at Function.ESLintPlugin.formatResults (C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint-plugin.js:52:66)
    at ESLintPlugin.getErrors (C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint-plugin.js:49:29)
    at ESLintPlugin.onMessage (C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\languageService\eslint\bin\eslint-plugin.js:30:42)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\jsLanguageServicesImpl\js-language-service.js:104:39)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:239:10)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (readline.js:376:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:375:11)
```

I verified that my settings are completely the same in the old version of IDEA, so

1. My node interpretor is specified correctly (`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`)
2. ESLint package is under node_modules: `~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint`
3. Configuration file is set to be searched automatically.
4. The path to the `.eslistrules` is specified correctly.

So, ***what could be the issue in this case?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25884.
What `ESLint` version do you use? Please try upgrading the the latest version

Comment: True, it might be because of that. I am using Node.js version 6.9.5 and ESLint 0.24.1, I assume that these two also might have some dependencies. I will try to update to see if that resolves the issue.